# Issue with callback on polling Angular API call

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, poller

I have a continuously polling API request. I'm using the angular-poller service to assist with this.

```js
     var gamesPoller = poller.get(apiURL, {
         method: 'GET',
         delay: 6000,
   // smart: true,
         argumentsArray: [
             {
                 params: {
                     token: token
                 }
             }
         ]
     });

     gamesPoller.promise.then(function(response) {
   
   $log.debug('promise resolved, data assigned');
   $scope.gameData =  response.data.List;
   $log.debug($scope.gameData);
   
  }, function(response) {
   
   $log.warn('Error in $http - getGames in controller...');
   
  }, callback);
```

In the network panel, I see the request made, resolving with a 200, and the response data. And it is making the request every 6 seconds like it should. However, the data isn't getting assigned to the $scope var. And nothing in the promise is being assigned/run.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the view code needs to be set in the call

```js
     gamesPoller.promise.then(null, null, function(response) {
   
   $log.debug(response.data);
   $cookies.put('Token', response.data.Token);
   $log.debug('getGames: ' + response.data.List);
   return $scope.gameData =  response.data.List;
   console.log($scope.gameData);
   
  }, function(response) {
   
   $log.warn('Error in $http - getGames in controller...');
   
  });
```